# Amazon SNS publishing topic

Tags: amazon-sns

I am working on Amazon SNS service, which sends notifications to the endpoint  (email,http,https,etc..). I can see the message sending format options either in Raw or Json, by any means do we have any option available that we can publish the message in "XML" format.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only JSON and Raw messages are supported, however, if you need to push an XML message - you can send it as a  "Raw" one - it'll work for all channels. But, if you want to customize your message on receiving device, e.g. add custom icon or play a custom sound on message receive - there is no alternative to JSON format in Amazon SNS right now.